# Php7 does not work with short-tags

Tags: apache2, php

I have installed Apache2 MariaDB and PHP7 for use on localhost, but PHP does not work. The Apache webside looks as normal while phpinfo.php only gives me a blank page. I used to install with 'apt-get install lamp-server^', but I wanted MariaDB, so I installed every single package including some PHP extensions and phpmyadmin. I have no idea of how to get php working. Any clues?

```
~ # php -v
PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
```

phpinfo.php:

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: Did you inatall `libapache2-mod-php7.0` also if not please do then restart apache

Comment: You need to enable php7.0 module for Apache: `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0 && sudo a2enmod php7.0 && sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`.

Comment: libapache2-mod-php7.0 already installed

Comment: Module php7.0 already enabled

Comment: Try with `<?php phpinfo(); ?> `. By default php7.0 doesn't support short open tags - `<?`.

Comment: @prebre I wrote an answer. If you find it for helpful you could accept it :) http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Sorry, I am still a bit confused about this forum, but now I have accepted your (BTW very useful) answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, PHP 7 does not supports short open tags `<?`.

It is described in the article [PHP tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) from [php.net](http://php.net/).

You need to use the full open tag `<?php`. Or, if you have PHP programs which are written for previous versions of PHP, you can change this rule in these ways:

- you can add next directive into `your-apache2-virtualhost.conf` (or `.htaccess`) file:

  ```
  php_flag short_open_tag on
  ```
- into the file `/etc/php/7.x/apache2/php.ini` you can set:

  ```
  short_open_tag = on
  ```

Don't forget to restart Apache2:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```